# Access the previous and next arrows on a web page

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape the following website's posts. I have written the code that will give me the max_id or the latest post number. For example, for http://papa-gen.livejournal.com/: if I have the max_id in theory I will be able to create a for loop 1 through the max_id and I should be able to scrape all of the posts.

The problem is that there are not as many posts as the max_id. For example, the max_id for the website above is 2870789 for the post for December 17th, but the post for December 16th has the number 2870614, a difference of 175. If I loop through all the 2870789, I will reach each post, but the code will of course not be very efficient. My idea is to access the previous and forward buttons on the website using my python code and loop in this manner.

Could someone explain how I could accomplish this using Scrapy?

Comment: you can set up rules for which links to follow, using a regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy has [extensive documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/).  There is [an example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) of using the `CrawlSpider` class to accomplish what you're describing, which you can modify to look something like this...

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'livejournal.com'
    allowed_domains = ['livejournal.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.papa-gen.livejournal.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('skip=', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # here is where the parsing happens
        pass
```

The basic idea is to specify rules that match the links.  Scrapy with add them to a list of urls to visit and then call the `callback` function with the page data when the url is fetched.